# Unable to mount "lvm2" volume

Tags: centos, mount

I had to reinstall CentOS on a system with a separate disk array for data.  I installed on the OS disks and kept the other disk array as storage (so they were not formatted).

When I try to mount the disks, I'm blocked due to unknown filesystem lvm2.

First some background.  The system has two arrays of drives.  One is for the OS (CentOS 6), the other for Data.   Here is the physical disk count on the machine:

```
#   Description                                     Total Gigs
2   HARD DRIVE, 300GB, SAS6, 10, 2.5, H-CE, E/C      600
6   HARD DRIVE, 600G, SAS6, 10, 2.5, W-SIR, E/C     3600
```

The two smaller drives are mirrored as 300g - this is where the OS lives.

The volume names are not listed when using `pvs`

```
PV          VG       Fmt  Att PSize  PFree
/dev/sda5   vg_mybox lvm2 a-- 276g   0
/dev/sdb1            lvm2 --- 1.8t   1.8t
/dev/sdc1            lvm2 --- 948g   948.67g
```

The PSize and PFree lines worry me.

Here's output from `pvscan`

```
  PV /dev/sda5   VG vg_ursula   lvm2 [276.34 GiB / 0    free]
  PV /dev/sdb1                  lvm2 [1.80 TiB]
  PV /dev/sdc1                  lvm2 [948.67 GiB]
  Total: 3 [3.00 TiB] / in use: 1 [276.34 GiB] / in no VG: 2 [2.73 TiB]
```

and `lvscan`

```
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_mybox/LogVol05' [29.30 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_mybox/LogVol04' [48.83 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_mybox/LogVol03' [48.83 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_mybox/lv_root' [111.74 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_mybox/lv_home' [9.77 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_mybox/lv_swap' [27.89 GiB] inherit
```

and `vgscan`

```
  Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
  Found volume group "vg_ursula" using metadata type lvm2
```

and `vcgk -vvv`

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/25ddd3280a34364fa186

`file -s /dev/sdb1`

```
/dev/sdb1: LVM2 (Linux Logical Volume Manager) , UUID: B1bLeFveeDcnfZ2i0tuqWtHgSd6UAgM
```

`file -s /dev/sdc1`

```
/dev/sdc1: LVM2 (Linux Logical Volume Manager) , UUID: SMMVLUKEuBPHuTeoarMkDAlJDDY1Gm2
```

and

`pvdisplay /dev/sdb1`

```
  "/dev/sdb1" is a new physical volume of "1.80 TiB"
  --- NEW Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdb1
  VG Name               
  PV Size               1.80 TiB
  Allocatable           NO
  PE Size               0   
  Total PE              0
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          0
  PV UUID               B1bLeF-veeD-cnfZ-2i0t-uqWt-HgSd-6UAgMA
```

`pvdisplay /dev/sdc1`

```
  "/dev/sdc1" is a new physical volume of "948.67 GiB"
  --- NEW Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdc1
  VG Name               
  PV Size               948.67 GiB
  Allocatable           NO
  PE Size               0   
  Total PE              0
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          0
  PV UUID               SMMVLU-KEuB-PHuT-eoar-MkDA-lJDD-Y1Gm2g
```

When installing this OS, I only moved the 276g drive to the "Install" list and left the other two as storage only.  When I reviewed the format/partition settigns, the two storage drives did not have a check under the Format column.

[image]

What are my next steps to mount and get the data?

Comment: Have you enabled lvm on the two unrecognised disks?

Comment: Haven't done anything yet.  Goal #1 is not not destroy any data on those disks.

Comment: Oh... That changes things a bit... what was the file format on the discs pre-install?

Comment: The disks couldn't have been ext4 if they were lvm containers. Please clarify.

Comment: Output of `vgscan` and `lvscan -D` please

Comment: This is the most recent fstab line I have for that drive. 
`/dev/sdb1  /www   ext3 defaults 1 2`

Comment: @roaima I've added `vgscan` output.  I get `lvscan: invalid option -- 'D'
  Error during parsing of command line.`

Comment: So are these disks lvm volumes or not? Your question seems to suggest they are, but here in the contents you're saying otherwise

Comment: @roaima to be honest I do not have adequate documentation to show how these drives were set up during install several years ago and am trying to piece it together now.

Comment: I assume that `mkdir -p /www ; mount -o ro /dev/sdb1 /www` is what fails? Precise error message please

Comment: error: 
`mount: unknown filesystem type 'LVM2_member'`

Comment: here is `vcgk -vvv`:  
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/25ddd3280a34364fa186

Answer (score 0):

It is strange that your PVs are not assigned to any VG and all the parameters are zero. Looks like formatted.

1.) Boot SystemRescue CD and test if it can detect the LVs on the disk.
So you can backup the data.
Run

```
pvscan
vgchange -ay
```

If it not works lets see what pvck can tell you:

```
pvck -d -v /dev/sdb1
pvck -d -v /dev/sdc1
```

2.) Without knowing where the LV partitions are the FS cannot be mounted.
Without FS it's hard to access the files.
As last resort you could use file carving tools to save as much data as possible: See scalpel and foremost.

Comment: Tried `vgchange -ay` last night.   The only volume showing afterwards is *vg_ursula* (per `vgscan`).

Comment: I'm very familiar with `vgcfgbackup` now, but did not know to include this in my server backups before.   I've already updated my other server backup scripts accordingly.   The previous VG config would make my life much easier today.  :(