# Restoring VG configuration from recovered drive

Tags: centos, configuration, hard-disk, lvm

Had to reinstall CentOS on a server with three RAID 1 arrays.  I installed the OS on sda (300g), and left sdb and sdc alone (they were not formatted or otherwise fiddled with).

The OS is up but I've been [unable to mount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231650/unable-to-mount-lvm2-volume/231840) the data drives, presumably because the vg config wasn't carried over.  I wasn't backing up the VG configuration, but it appears that I may have recovered it with `dd`

In the snippet below, LogVol05, LogVol03, and LogVol02 were volume names from the previous installation.

**First**, does the config below basically look kosher?

**Second**, if it looks OK, how would I go about incorporating it into the existing VG configuration?

```
logical_volumes {
LogVol05 {
id = "ZdFwA8-lj4Y-XwD0-hFMB-iHf8-kZdo-VfJy89"
status = ["READ", "WRITE", "VISIBLE"]
flags = []
creation_host = "ursula2012"
creation_time = 1378846949
segment_count = 2

segment1 {
start_extent = 0
extent_count = 471858

type = "striped"
stripe_count = 1    # linear

stripes = [
"pv1", 0
]
}
segment2 {
start_extent = 471858
extent_count = 225240

type = "striped"
stripe_count = 1    # linear

stripes = [
"pv2", 0
]
}
}
id = "Ex8O6x-y9bt-nDDZ-tqfM-L5hG-GKPM-O1YcsS"
status = ["READ", "WRITE", "VISIBLE"]
flags = []
creation_host = "ursula2012"
creation_time = 1378847075
segment_count = 1

segment1 {
start_extent = 0
extent_count = 15000

type = "striped"
stripe_count = 1    # linear

stripes = [
"pv0", 0
]
}
}

LogVol03 {
id = "o2RB9c-Idd9-WGCT-54o4-e2ZZ-EtBn-q8s9Vo"
status = ["READ", "WRITE", "VISIBLE"]
flags = []
creation_host = "ursula2012"
creation_time = 1378847083
segment_count = 1

segment1 {
start_extent = 0
extent_count = 15000

type = "striped"
stripe_count = 1    # linear

stripes = [
"pv0", 15000
]
}
}
LogVol02 {
id = "Szb39M-Kp37-j5di-kY9I-g2VV-SOkk-oMj1d0"
status = ["READ", "WRITE", "VISIBLE"]
flags = []
creation_host = "ursula2012"
creation_time = 1378847092
segment_count = 1

segment1 {
start_extent = 0
extent_count = 37500

type = "striped"
stripe_count = 1    # linear

stripes = [
"pv0", 30000
]
}
}
}
}
# Generated by LVM2 version 2.02.98(2)-RHEL6 (2012-10-15): Tue Sep 10 17:04:52 2013

contents = "Text Format Volume Group"
version = 1

description = ""

creation_host = "ursula2012"    # Linux ursula2012 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Feb 22 00:31:26 UTC 2013 x86_64
creation_time = 1378847092  # Tue Sep 10 17:04:52 2013
```

Comment: Glad to see you got a little further since yesterday.  I don't really know what your next step is, but based on some preliminary research, look into the `vgcfgrestore` command, and the `vgimport` commands. With those it *may* be as simple as pointing them at your recovered meta data and letting it work its magic, but I can't find any solid evidence of other people with a similar enough problem to yours as to be a 1-1 exchange.

Comment: I'm imaging both sdb and sdc tonight.   Takes a while since it's having to pipe across USB 2.0.    Have you heard of or used [rstudio](http://www.r-studio.com/)?

Comment: @Gravy any ideas here:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232546/wrong-fs-type-bad-option-bad-superblock-when-attempting-to-mount-restored-volu ?