# wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock when attempting to mount restored volume

Tags: centos, mount

I restored a LVM group from a recovered config today (background [#1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231650/unable-to-mount-lvm2-volume/231840), [#2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231886/restoring-vg-configuration-from-recovered-drive)). Full images were made of the disks prior to issuing the following command.

```
[root@ursula diskissues]# vgcfgrestore -f ursula2012_restore.cfg vg_ursula2012
  Restored volume group vg_ursula2012
```

Then

```
vgchange -ay
```

Next, I added a line to `/etc/fstab`, but I try to `mount -a` I get:

```
[root@ursula diskissues]# mount -a
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/vg_ursula2012-lv_www,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

from dmesg:

```
EXT4-fs (dm-6): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
```

Here's fstab:

```
/dev/mapper/vg_ursula-lv_root /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
UUID=1e1f9db2-8231-407c-bc0e-18ae5066231e /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/vg_ursula-lv_home /home                   ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/vg_ursula-LogVol05 /tmp                    ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/vg_ursula-LogVol04 /usr                    ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/vg_ursula-LogVol03 /var                    ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/vg_ursula-lv_swap swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/vg_ursula2012-lv_www /www                    ext4    defaults        1 2
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
```

pvs:

```
[root@ursula diskissues]# pvs
  PV         VG            Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree 
  /dev/sda5  vg_ursula     lvm2 a--  276.34g     0 
  /dev/sdb1  vg_ursula2012 lvm2 a--    1.80t     0 
  /dev/sdc1  vg_ursula2012 lvm2 a--  948.67g 18.83g
```

lv

```
[root@ursula diskissues]# lvs
  LV       VG            Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  lv_root  vg_ursula2012 -wi-a-----  50.00g                                                    
  lv_www   vg_ursula2012 -wi-a-----   2.66t                                                    
  LogVol03 vg_ursula     -wi-ao----  48.83g                                                    
  LogVol04 vg_ursula     -wi-ao----  48.83g                                                    
  LogVol05 vg_ursula     -wi-ao----  29.30g                                                    
  lv_home  vg_ursula     -wi-ao----   9.77g                                                    
  lv_root  vg_ursula     -wi-ao---- 111.74g                                                    
  lv_swap  vg_ursula     -wi-ao----  27.89g
```

vgscan

```
[root@ursula diskissues]# vgscan
  Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
  Found volume group "vg_ursula2012" using metadata type lvm2
  Found volume group "vg_ursula" using metadata type lvm2

[root@ursula diskissues]# lvscan
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_ursula2012/lv_www' [2.66 TiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_ursula2012/lv_root' [50.00 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_ursula/LogVol05' [29.30 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_ursula/LogVol04' [48.83 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_ursula/LogVol03' [48.83 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_ursula/lv_root' [111.74 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_ursula/lv_home' [9.77 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/vg_ursula/lv_swap' [27.89 GiB] inherit
```

Comment: First, wow, Way to go with this! amazing progress, second, First suggestion would be to run `e2fsck` on the recovered `logical volumes` and let it correct errors, if you have not already.

Comment: I just ran `e2fsck -n /dev/vg_ursula2012/lv_root`, here's that output:  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b1c3543ec0173e7ef81e

Comment: Alright, assuming you *do* have a backup of the drives, I would run it with `-y` and let it try to correct everything. May do the trick. Definitely make sure you have them backed up though, just to be safe.

Comment: I do have backups, but on a very slow USB external drive.   I verified that the images match the devices by running md5sum against each (which took quite a while across both images and devices).

Comment: Worst case scenario I do not believe running the `e2fsck -y /dev/vg_ursula2012/lv_root` will make things *worse*, I do think it has a good chance to helping the situation though.

Comment: Agreed -- worst case is that it's unreadable, and that's where you are already. :)

Comment: Ok just made a snapshot of the smaller partition and ran `e2fsck` on that.  Success!  Next is the much larger partition.

Comment: That seems promising, hopefully the larger one will go off without a hitch! Let me know how it turns out, if for some reason the larger one still has trouble I'll try to do some more research.

Comment: Can I suggest some edits on your answer?  There are a couple steps I took that are beneficial for others to know and use (assuming someone ever makes the same mistake I did last week!)

Comment: Absolutely. Best to be complete, definitely

Answer (score 3):

*(moved from comments to make answer more searchable)*

Allow the disk errors to be corrected with `e2fsck`

```
e2fsck -y /dev/vg_ursula2012/lv_root
e2fsck -y /dev/vg_ursula2012/lv_www
```

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, I had this exact same error message on a logical volume group and e2fsck did nothing to resolve my issue. In my case, I simply had a typo in my fstab file.

Original fstab:

```
/dev/mapper/my--vg-mydata       /mydata ext4 default 0 0
```

Generated the same error on this post:

```
[root@server2 ~]# mount -a
mount: /mydata: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/my--vg-mydata, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Mounting by hand worked just fine though:

```
[root@server2 ~]# mount /dev/mapper/my--vg-mydata /mydata/
[root@server2 ~]# touch /mydata/test
[root@server2 ~]# ll !$
ll /mydata/test
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Dec 11 17:53 /mydata/test
```

Once I corrected my /etc/fstab file to use **defaults** (plural) instead of **default** (singular), `mount -a` worked correctly again.